# generating a datatables on pageload using ajaxSource to call a method in java service class

Tags: jakarta-ee

This is my javascript:
generating a datatables on pageload using ajaxSource to call a method in java service class....what i have keep displaying "loading..." in html but it does not load anything

If I put that url in my browser it does show data as json string, now I just need to present it in table form

```
$(document).ready(function() {

               $('#example').dataTable({

                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "iDisplayLength": 1,
                    "bLengthChange": true,
                    "dataType":"json",
                    "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost:8181/TangibleAMS_Sys/REST/Employee/RetrieveEmployee",

                    "Columns": [
                                {"data": "name"}
                                ]                           


                });



} );
```

Comment: thats why you defined: "dataType":"json"

Comment: @YethabaDid you see any error at your  browser development console?

Comment: @erhun yeah "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined:
   jquery.dataTables.min.js:59"..